# Facing PKIX path building failed exception in selenium broken link script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ssl-certificate, httprequest

I am using below lines of code to verify broken links

```
   huc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url).openConnection());
   huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
   huc.setReadTimeout(5000);
   huc.connect();
   respCode = huc.getResponseCode();
```

when script enters huc.connect() line , it throws below exception.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

How can I solve it? I need to run this script locally and also in github actions pipeline.

Comment: How did you declare `huc`?

Answer (score 2):

You get this error when your Website certificate is not added to Trusted store. Please follow below step to add certificate to trusted store.

1. Open the website and Download the certificate by clicking on the lock icon->Connection is secure->Certification-> click on the root->Certification path->Copy to file-> and store in your local system with an alias name.

[image: cert1]
[image: cert2]
[image: cert3]

2. Now you need to add certificate to $JAVA_HOME\lib\security\cacerts using below command

> ```
> keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <AliasName> -file   <certificate> -keystore <KeystoreFile> -storepass <Password>
> ```

eg:

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias myaddedcertaliasname
 -file /localsystempath/to/my/cert/myCert.cer -keystore /path/to/my/jdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts/keystore.jks -storepass
 changeit
```

Please note the default password for key store is changeit.

Once you import the certificate to your key store you should no more get this error